# iOS - Set app wide kern and line spacing for UILabel and UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

So I want to apply a kern and line spacing of 1.5 to all my `UILabel` and `UIButton` throughout the app. I've been able to apply one by one using NSAttributedString, and subclassing, but in all cases you have to call the method to apply kern after the text is set. Is there a default setting or maybe a way to subclass where I just need to inherit from the subclass and the kerning applies for itself?

It's a pretty large scale app with hundreds of labels, buttons and text fields spanning over multiple storyboards.

Custom methods and extensions are not the ideal solution for this case because then I'd still have to use the method every time the text is set.

Comment: Why don't you use @IBDesignable and adjust the attributes in storyboard itself? Also, do add the code that you're using for kerning and line spacing.

Comment: IMO, almost always use a subClass for frequently used native/thirdparty api's. It doesn't hurt much but provide full control to change effortlessly  at an app level. I would suggest implementing this even if it requires a lot of effort so that you are saved in future. Otherwise, i can only think of `Swizzling`(not sure at the moment where exactly you can put this) because `appearance` proxy has limitations.